How does data reduction affect the Cramer-Rao bound?
Suppose we have a random sample $\mathbf X=(X_1,\dots,X_N)$ with $X_n\sim F_X(\boldsymbol\theta)$ and $\boldsymbol\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m)$.
For an unbiased estimator $\tilde{\boldsymbol\theta}$ of $\boldsymbol\theta$ the Cramer-Rao bound gives
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(\tilde{\boldsymbol\theta})\geq I_\mathbf X^{-1}(\boldsymbol\theta),
$$
where $\geq$ is taken to mean $\mathsf{Cov}(\tilde{\boldsymbol\theta})-I_\mathbf X^{-1}(\theta)$ is positive semidefinite.
Now suppose we define a statistic $T(\mathbf X)$, which may or may not be sufficient and suppose we derive a new unbiased estimator $\tilde{\boldsymbol\psi}$, which is a function of $T(\mathbf X)$. Does it follow that the Cramer-Rao bound is
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(\tilde{\boldsymbol\psi})\geq I_{T(\mathbf X)}^{-1}(\boldsymbol\theta)?
$$

Simple example indicating the affirmative:
$\mathbf X=(X_1,\dots,X_N)$ with $X_n\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then
$$
I_\mathbf X(\lambda)=\frac{N}{\lambda}.
$$
Then for an unbiased estimator $\tilde{\lambda}$ one has
$$
\mathsf{Var}\tilde\lambda\geq\frac{\lambda}{N}.
$$
But now suppose we define $T(\mathbf X)=X_1$ so that
$$
I_{T(\mathbf X)}(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}.
$$
Then for an unbiased estimator $\tilde\lambda^\prime$, which is a function of $T(\mathbf X)$ we have
$$
\mathsf{Var}(\tilde\lambda^\prime)\geq\lambda.
$$

Well, put $Y = T(X)$, use the original bound with $Y$ in place of $X$...
